# Azure function Calculated MD5 does not match existing property

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

Hello i have this error since yesterday when debuging Azure Function
i think it have to do with local dev storage cuz when i publish in azure all work well.

my local.settings.json is:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "schedule": "*/1 * * * * *"
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "crypto_dbEntities": //.................
  }
```

ERROR:

> [13/01/2019 13:33:29] The listener for function 'Function1' was unable
>   to start. Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: Calculated MD5 does not
>   match existing property. [13/01/2019 13:33:29] The listener for
>   function 'Function1' was unable to start.
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: Calculated MD5 does not match existing
>   property.

How can i fixe this?.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found a workaround (i think my local storage was corupted)
1)uninstall Microsoft Azure Storage Emulator 
2)Reinstall it From Azure SDK using one of the methode in this doc
[AZURE STORAGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator)

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem I cleared Azure Storage Emulator using

cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator
.\AzureStorageEmulator.exe clear all